# How to pass python variables to Popen?

Tags: python, shell, hadoop

I am trying to delete a hadoop directory using a python script

```
__removeDir__ = subprocess.call(['hadoop','fs','-rmr',targetdir],stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

targetdir is a python variable from the same script.

The above command is not working. Also, I would like to know if there is any API provided to the hadoop filesystem in python.

Comment: Please specify what "not working" means. Are you getting an exception? If so, post the traceback.

Comment: `targetdir` is path i assume, instead of `call` use `Popen`.